# Wrong Output,but why?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, while-loop, distribution

User will give N,S respectively

If the value of N is 3, i.e i have 3 boxes and the input of S is 6.
Then I am coding in such a manner that in the 1st case(n=3), 1 is added to each box,then again(n=2) 1 is added to each box (A,B,C) excluding the last box, again(n=1) 1 is added to each box excluding the last box as well as the second last box.
And the total number of balls left in each box is to displayed after distribution of total value S,

For example :

It looks like this, where a,b,c are the 3 boxes. 
n=3 and s=6

```
A B C
1 1 1
1 1
1
-----
3 2 1 //output to be displayed
```

again if the input of n ans s are 4 and 9
then output would be,

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1
-------
3 3 2 1 //output to be displayed
```

again if the input of n ans s are 3 and 4
then output would be,

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
1 
-------
2 1 1 1 //output to be displayed
```

again if the input of n ans s are 4 and 2
then output would be,

```
A B C D
1 1 
-------
1 1 0 0 //output to be displayed
```

for n max value of s = n*(n+1)/2

Actually in this case the the complexity of the code cant be O(n^2). SO this was my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,s,y,x1;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&s);
    int b[n];
    memset(b,0,n);
    x1=n;
    j=0;
        while(s>0)
        {
            y=j%n;
            if(j!=n-1)
            {
                b[y]++;
                s--;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                b[y]++;
                s--;
                j=0;
                n--;
            }
        }
    for(i=0;i<x1;++i)
        {
            printf("%d ",b[i]);
        }
return 0;
}
```

But after executing the code,The output given by my code:

```
where n = 4 and s = 9
the output is : 3 32631 -747449654 32629

where n = 3 and s = 5
the output is :2 2 4195586
```

Why is this happening ? I dont want to use nested for loops!
But whats wrong in here ? please help  me!

Comment: You do know that `memset(b, 0, n)` sets the first `n` *bytes* of `b` to zero, but `b` is an array of `n` `int`s?

Comment: By the way, as an improvement I would suggest always giving the variables in your programs more descriptive names, such as "box" instead of "b" and "numBoxes" instead of "n".  It will help you and others who  look at your code to follow the logic more easily.

Comment: What is the time complexity of this code ?

Comment: @EricBarr What is the time complexity of this code

Answer (score 2):

`void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );`

`num` is the number of bytes, so

`memset(b,0,n);`

should be

`memset(b,0,n*sizeof(int));`

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/I9LzdT)

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to `memset` is the number of **bytes** to set. Since `b` is an array of `int`, it has `4*n` bytes that need to be cleared, assuming 32-bit ints. The correct code is

```
memset( b, 0, sizeof(b) );
```

Comment: Thnx, 
That was my mistake , sorry for that :(

Comment: No worries, everybody makes mistakes :)

Comment: @MoinakDebnath The `while` loop is based solely on `s`, and `s` decrements every time, so the complexity of the `while` loop is *O(s)*. The `for` loop is based solely on `n`, since `x1=n`, so the complexity of the `for` loop is *O(n)*. Overall, you have *O(n+s)*. That can be simplified to *O(n)* if `n` is larger than `s`, or *O(s)* is `s` is larger than `n`.